# Split Line by Point and applying different styles for the split layer depending upon the Point layerlayer QGIS

Tags: qgis, splitting

I am using QGIS. [image]
I have a point layer and line layer. I want to split the line layer by point layer and color the line layer according to the content of the 'Name' filed in the point layer. The 'Name' field contains two values : Black and Red.

I tried '*split lines at points*' but I couldn't achieve this.

[image]